# NoFollow Entire Website

Tags: seo, robots.txt, nofollow, noindex

By default whenever you disable indexing via Admin Settings

> [ x ] Discourage search engines from indexing this site

It adds a meta tag in the header like so:

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
```

How do I change that to be `nofollow` instead of `follow`?  I find it odd it enables "follow" and overall want it `noindex,nofollow`.

I could echo directly into `wp_head` but this doesn't account for pages such as wp-login and the likes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thought this was a great question so I went digging.  In default-filters.php on line 208 there's `add_action('wp_head', 'noindex', 1);` as of WordPress 4.1.  The noindex() function in turn checks to see if you have set blog_public option to 0.  If you have, it calls wp_no_robots() which is simply:

```
function wp_no_robots() {
    echo "<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />\n";
}
```

Neither of last methods are filterable, but a simple plugin will do the trick to remove the hook:

```
/*
 * Declare plugin stuff here
 */

remove_action('wp_head','noindex',1);
```

Now, you're free to hook your own action on to echo out what you want.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_no_follow', 1);

function my_no_follow() {
    if ( '0' == get_option('blog_public') ) {
        echo "<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You would also want to run it on the wp-`login.php` header file also, which is excluded from `wp_head` ( or seems to be ). Looking for blog_public is a good point though to make it more usable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this ended up working for me. I was more hoping for some kind of better filter but it works just as well. Throw this in a `functions.php` file and you're good to go.

```
/** No Index No Follow Entire Website **/
function nofollow_meta() {
    echo "<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'nofollow_meta', 1 );
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'nofollow_meta', 1 );
```